# Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool - Error while selecting from quoted fields

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am getting an error while selecting from a CSV file that contains quoted fields using **Serverless/ OnDemand SQL Pool** in Azure Synapse. The data contains the field terminator (,) within the fields, but it's quoted with double quotes. I have even tried to specify the FIELDQUOTE explicitly even though I am using the default quote in the data.

My file contains the data as below

```
"number", "text"
1, "one"
2, "two"
11, "one, one"
12, "one, two"
```

The SQL that I ran is as below

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/data/test_quoted_fields.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIELDQUOTE = '"',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE
    ) AS [result]
```

And the error message is as below

```
Error handling external file: 'Quotes '' must be inside quoted fields at [byte: 10]. '. File/External table name: 'https://mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/data/test_quoted_fields.csv'
```

Please note that I am running the query using **Serverless/ OnDemand SQL Pool**.

Can someone help please? Thanks

[image: Screenshot from Synapse Studio]

Data in ADLS Portal looks as below
**In Edit mode**
[image: Edit Mode Data]

**In Preview mode**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I so appears that having .csv in excel and after uploading to ADLS would add additional " " around quoted fields so as to be seen as a string. And it does seem to work well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karthik for looking into it. I missed the comma just in the post here. The code did have the comma, otherwise I would have got syntax error. I have added a screenshot with the statement I am running (that includes the comma) and also the error. It is strange that this works for you. Anything you can suggest. I am working on a macbook and the file was created in the mac too.

Comment: Can you try preview the `csv` in adls portal to see if the structure is right

Comment: Yes, the data looks in the portal looks OK to me. I have just added the screenshots of both Edit and Preview mode to the question above. Thanks again for looking into this.

Comment: I think I just found during repro just secs before, updated answer now 

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the right direction. The issue was the additional space between the 2 columns after the comma. Removing the additional space fixes the issue. Thank you!